# Anchor links not working with JS generated content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Mustache.js to generate content. Another page contains anchor links that link to content generated by Mustache. The anchor links from the other page are not scrolling the browser to the appropriate content. I assume this is happening because the content has no height when the page first loads. The content height will vary, so I cannot hard code the height. Any ideas on a simple solution? This appears to be Chrome only (so far), and happens only occasionally.

Comment: really? Where is your code and a demonstration of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting a height for the elements in question.